# LoggingFilter not invoked - gives HTTP 404 - Not Found error

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlet-filters, web.xml, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.3.1, Tomcat 7.0, maven.

I have a simple jersey servlet:

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class JerseyResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List <SecurityControlDTO> getControls() throws HibernateException {
    SecurityControlDTOManager manager = new SecurityControlDTOManager();
    return manager.getControls();
  }
}
```

And want to add a LoggingFilter.

This is my web.xml:

```
<!-- Jersey Mapping -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rbs.wisexec.controlservice.rest;</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-auth</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-auth</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

When I run the tomcat server, the server starts up but then when I try to access the URL I get a "HTTP Status 404 - not found" error. I have debug breakpoints in filter class so I can see that it never gets invoked.

I have tried various different ways of configuring the loggingFilter in the web.xml i.e. putting the:

```
<init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter</param-name>
                <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
            </init-param>
```

Inside of the servlet tag - this runs the server and the resource is shown but again the filters are not invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure your application via `web.xml` and not by using subclass of [javax.ws.rs.core.Application](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html), you can modify your web descriptor in this way:

```
<!-- Jersey Mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rbs.wisexec.controlservice.rest;</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The important thing is the second `init-param` which states that `LoggingFilter` should be added to the list of JAX-RS providers in your application. Parameter is taken from [ServerProperties](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) class where you can find description of this parameter ([ServerProperties.PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES)) as well as other possibilities to configure your Jersey application.